# Pivot table VBA error 5 in Excel 14

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to write code to create a pivot table using VBA, but I am getting an error message 5 when trying to run.  I've even tried recording a macro and the code recorded isn't working.

```
Sheets("All Data").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "All Data!R4C1:R39C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="All Data!R6C12", TableName:="PivotTable7", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Can anyone help with where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the error when you run the macro on a new workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Bill, What you have done is correct, but only single quotes are missing around sheetname in table destination and source data.

Try this Code:

```
Sheets("All Data").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'All Data'!R4C1:R39C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="'All Data'!R6C12", TableName:="PivotTable7", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

**Note:** I have included SheetName *AllData* with single quote.